# How to take a image url from a datagridview and put it into a picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, picturebox, imageurl

Good day

I am needing help

I want to take an image url that is in a datagridview which is connected to a database and add the url to a picturebox in c#.

I have searched for it but had no luck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems way broad. Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem at least? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came right

```
    private void dgData_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        picData.ImageLocation = dgData.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        picData.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
```

This worked very well

Answer (score 0):

You can create picture type cell and put in it pictures. which you can show in Picture box when cell was clicked or entered.
Or you can have only URL link in datagrid cells and when you click cell then URL link will be used to get image from.

```
    private void bt_AddPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add image to datagrid view
        //You can add picture from SQL database instead.
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Image.FromFile(@"c:\Users\Programmer\Desktop\tmp\tmp\Capture.PNG"));
    }

    private void bt_ShowPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show image from datagrid view in picture box.
        //You can use it in event on cellEnter
        pictureBox1.Image = ( dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value as Image);
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
```